# Change TextView color when changing theme

Tags: android

#### Question

How can I have the text color change dynamically when the theme changes?

#### Problem

[image: TextView]

Text color dynamically changes when the theme is changed

Comment: Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/themes

Comment: I am also telling the same thing .

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You can change the text color when changing the theme.

**Ligth Theme**

```
<style name="SimpleTextColor">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    </style>
```

**Dark/Night Theme**

```
<style name="SimpleTextColor">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    </style>
```

**Applye in XML**

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_st_name"
                style="@style/SimpleTextColor"  <!--apply like this-->
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Add this `style` to your `TextView` and the problem should be solved:

> style="**@style/Theme.Material3.DynamicColors.Light**"

### Example

```
<TextView
            android:text="@string/testText"
      ----> style="@style/Theme.Material3.DynamicColors.Light" <-----
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:id="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks, this works like **magic**! It dynamically changes `textColor` when switching white/dark mode.